# JQueryUI in Chrome extension content script

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

After putting jquery-ui(css and js) and jquery in the manifest, I can use jq selectors ($), however jquery-ui seems to be inaccessible. For example, I'm trying to insert a resizable div in a content-script (content_script.js):

```
var $div = document.createElement('div');
$div.id = 'divId';
$div.innerHTML = 'inner html';
$("body").append($div);//works without error
$("#divId").css("background-color","yellow");//works
//doesn't give resizable handles, however works in a regular html file:
$("#divId").resizable();
//however this also has issue:
document.getElementById("divId").style.resize = "both";
```

Manifest:

```
"css":["jquery-ui.css"],
"js": ["jquery-ui.js","jquery.js","content_script.js"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong load order - `jquery-ui` expects `jquery` to be loaded first.

```
"js": ["jquery.js", "jquery-ui.js", "content_script.js"]
```